# IP to ASN lookup using ClickHouse

Tags: ip-address, clickhouse

I have a table consisting of IP/CIDR and AS Number and a regular sFlow data table.

Since the sFlow data does not have an ASN, **I want to add ASN into sFlow data table** using IP/CIDR-ASN table.

*All IP addresses of sFlow data table are IPv6 data type ipv4 mapped.*

I read the ClickHouse docs > SQL Reference > Functions > Regular Functions > IP Addresses.

`isIPAddressInRange()` function is there, but I don't know how to use this function to solve this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. make ip ranges from ip/cidr
2. `IPv4StringToNum(start) <= IPv4StringToNum('my ip') and IPv4StringToNum(end) >= IPv4StringToNum('my ip')`
3. wow